# How to specifically use assembly inline in C?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, codeblocks

Let's say I have the following function in C:

```
void sum(){

      float a,b,ans; 
      a = 1.0; b = 2.0; //I do use scanf for a and b for for simplicity i'll just use random numbers
      ans = a+b;      
      printf("Answer is %.2f",ans);
    }
```

How can I make the exact same behavior (mathematically operate 2 variables and store the result in another variable) using inline assembly in C? Replacing only the ans = a+b line would be ideal, I'm using gcc or MinGW for windows version of Codeblock compilers if it changes anything.

Comment: They closed this question, but in any case, here follows: you can change the line `ans = a+b` for `asm  (   "movss (%0), %%xmm0;"  "movss (%1), %%xmm1;"  "addss %%xmm0, %%xmm1;"  "movss %%xmm1, (%2);"  :  : "r" (&a), "r" (&b), "r"(&ans)   );`

Comment: @AndréCaceres: that's extremely inefficient in that it forces everything into memory.  Much better is to use the registers directly: `asm("addss %2, %0" : "=r"(ans) : "0"(a), "r"(b));`

Comment: @Chris Dodd, I just copied the disassembly code from GCC in debug mode. But thank you for point a better alternative!

Comment: @ChrisDodd: `"r"` is a GP-integer register.  You want `"x"` for xmm registers.  `asm("addss %1, %0" : "+x"(dst) : "x"(src));`

Comment: @AndréCaceres: The asm in your first comment isn't even safe.  You destroy XMM0 and XMM1 without telling the compiler, and asking for a pointer in a register doesn't tell the compiler that you read or write the pointed-to memory.  Also, copying anti-optimized `-O0` asm output is terrible.  Write a function that takes two `float` args and returns a `float` so you can compile with optimization and see a stand-alone definition for it.  ([How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](//stackoverflow.com/q/38552116))

Comment: @PeterCordes could you elaborate on the part that the XMM0 and XMM1 is destroyed? I did not get it. Sorry.

Comment: The asm code in your template string uses `movss` loads into XMM0 and XMM1, replacing their old value.  So you step on the compiler's toes if it was expecting those registers to still hold some value later.  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Clobbers-and-Scratch-Registers